# Launchctl difference between load and start, unload and stop

Tags: launchd

I was reading through the launchctl man page and have a few questions about its functioning:

- What is the difference between load and start, unload and stop?
- Where do I find the job label for a daemon, is it in the plist file?

Answer (score 81):

### TL;DR

- **You typically want to use `launchctl load -w` and `launchctl unload -w`.**
- **`start` and `stop` are usually reserved for testing or debugging a job.**

### Details

- `launchctl start <label>`: Starts the job. This is usually reserved just for testing or debugging a particular job.
- `launchctl stop <label>`: Stops the job. Opposite of start, and it's possible that the job will immediately restart if the job is configured to stay running.

---

- `launchctl remove <label>`: Removes the job from `launchd`, but asynchronously. It will not wait for the job to actually stop before returning, so no error handling on this one.

---

- `launchctl load <path>`: Loads and starts the job as long as the job is not "disabled."
- `launchctl unload <path>`: Stops and unloads the job. The job will still restart on the next login/reboot.

---

- `launchctl load -w <path>`: Loads and starts the job while also marking the job as *"not disabled."* The job will restart on the next login/reboot.
- `launchctl unload -w <path>`: Stops and unloads *and disables* the job. The job will *NOT* restart on the next login/restart.

---

> *Where do I find the job label for a daemon, is it in the plist file?*

Yes, it's in the plist file and it typically matches the filename of the plist file.

Comment: BTW, use `launchctl list` to get all jobs loaded into launchctl.

Answer (score 10):

Loading and unloading tells launchd to load the configuration file. Whether it runs the program and under what conditions is determined by the plist file. A job that isn't currently running can be started with `launchctl start ...` and stopped with `launchctl stop ...`.

The label for the job is defined by the label key, and the name of the plist should also be the job label followed by the plist extension.

Comment: How does remove factor into this? Specifically how is it different from unload?

Comment: @chrisortman remove is like unload except that it does not wait for the job to stop first. It just returns immediately without checking if any errors occurred.