# start ntpd with launchdaemon

Tags: macos, launchd

I would like to start an ntpd on my MacOSX 10.8. ntpd is configured correctly and runs when started manually. 
I would like to start it on boot time with lauchdaemon.

I created this com.stefan.ntp.plist file in /Library/LaunchDaemons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.stefan.ntpd</string>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/usr/sbin/ntpd</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string></string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Added it to the Launchdaemon with

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.stefan.ntpd.plist
```

However, it does not start.

```
sh-3.2# launchctl list | grep ntpd
-   0   com.stefan.ntpd
sh-3.2# launchctl start com.stefan.ntpd
sh-3.2# launchctl list | grep ntpd
-   0   com.stefan.ntpd
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe try to use launchd to run a simple shell script which appends a timestamp to /tmp/hello.txt first and then try to include ntpd in a second step.

Answer (score 1):

There should be an `ntpd` process started by `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.ntp.ntpd.plist` by default in 10.8.

The plist is also missing `<key>RunAtLoad</key><true/>`, but I couldn't get this to work either:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.stefan.ntpd</string>
  <key>Program</key>
  <string>/usr/sbin/ntpd</string>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: It works wit <key>Program</key>
  <string>/usr/libexec/ntpd-wrapper</string>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `-w` flag in the `launchctl` command.  The `-w` flag will ensure that the daemon specified will start up automatically upon reboot.

See [Launchctl difference between load and start, unload and stop](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29056/launchctl-difference-between-load-and-start-unload-and-stop)

In your case, the command should be:

`sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.stefan.ntpd.plist`

And I would just slightly modify the `ntpd.plist` provided by Apple as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd>
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.stefan.ntpd</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/libexec/ntpd-wrapper</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <dict>
      <key>PathState</key>
      <dict>
    <key>/private/etc/ntp.conf</key>
    <true/>
      </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>EnableTransactions</key>
    <true/>
    <key>SHAuthorizationRight</key>
    <string>system.preferences</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

P.S.  If you want, you can also add to the plist the following key:

`<key>RunAtLoad</key>`

But I prefer using the the `-w` flag with `launchctl` instead.