# Console Message: "kernel: Sandbox: net.conceited.Ru System Policy: deny(1) mach-priv-task-port 391"

Tags: macos, error, kernel

I'm getting about 50 messages like the following on the console every second.

```
01/09/15 17:50:32,000   kernel[0]   Sandbox: net.conceited.Ru(295) System Policy: deny(1) mach-priv-task-port 402
01/09/15 17:50:32,000   kernel[0]   Sandbox: net.conceited.Ru(295) System Policy: deny(1) mach-priv-task-port 401
01/09/15 17:50:32,000   kernel[0]   Sandbox: net.conceited.Ru(295) System Policy: deny(1) mach-priv-task-port 400
01/09/15 17:50:32,000   kernel[0]   Sandbox: net.conceited.Ru(295) System Policy: deny(1) mach-priv-task-port 398
01/09/15 17:50:32,000   kernel[0]   Sandbox: net.conceited.Ru(295) System Policy: deny(1) mach-priv-task-port 397
01/09/15 17:50:32,000   kernel[0]   Sandbox: net.conceited.Ru(295) System Policy: deny(1) mach-priv-task-port 396
01/09/15 17:50:32,000   kernel[0]   Sandbox: net.conceited.Ru(295) System Policy: deny(1) mach-priv-task-port 395
01/09/15 17:50:32,000   kernel[0]   Sandbox: net.conceited.Ru(295) System Policy: deny(1) mach-priv-task-port 394
01/09/15 17:50:32,000   kernel[0]   Sandbox: net.conceited.Ru(295) System Policy: deny(1) mach-priv-task-port 393
01/09/15 17:50:32,000   kernel[0]   Sandbox: net.conceited.Ru(295) System Policy: deny(1) mach-priv-task-port 392
01/09/15 17:50:32,000   kernel[0]   Sandbox: net.conceited.Ru(295) System Policy: deny(1) mach-priv-task-port 389
01/09/15 17:50:32,000   kernel[0]   Sandbox: net.conceited.Ru(295) System Policy: deny(1) mach-priv-task-port 383
01/09/15 17:50:32,000   kernel[0]   Sandbox: net.conceited.Ru(295) System Policy: deny(1) mach-priv-task-port 379
01/09/15 17:50:32,000   kernel[0]   Sandbox: net.conceited.Ru(295) System Policy: deny(1) mach-priv-task-port 378
01/09/15 17:50:32,000   kernel[0]   Sandbox: net.conceited.Ru(295) System Policy: deny(1) mach-priv-task-port 377
01/09/15 17:50:32,000   kernel[0]   Sandbox: net.conceited.Ru(295) System Policy: deny(1) mach-priv-task-port 376
01/09/15 17:50:32,000   kernel[0]   Sandbox: net.conceited.Ru(295) System Policy: deny(1) mach-priv-task-port 375
01/09/15 17:50:32,000   kernel[0]   Sandbox: net.conceited.Ru(295) System Policy: deny(1) mach-priv-task-port 374
```

Could someone points me on what's happened and how can I avoid it?

Comment: It seems like it may be related to an old piece of software do you still use it? Conceited don't exist any more by the looks... Ru, is presumably Rubbernet for bandwidth monitoring...

Answer (score 5):

This is indeed Rubbernet as @unknowndomain mentions - I was getting a flood of messages that caused 100% CPU for syslogd, visible in Console.

Since Conceited have gone out of business, here is how to uninstall Rubbernet:

1. open the Rubbernet `.plist` file that was launching the daemon, which should be `/Library/LaunchDaemons/net.conceited.RubbernetDaemon.plist`
2. ensure Launchd doesn't restart the Rubbernet process with `launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/net.conceited.RubbernetDaemon.plist`
3. kill the Rubbernet process via Activity Monitor, or using `ps aux` and `kill`
4. remove `/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/net.conceited.RubbernetDaemon` (mentioned in the plist)
5. remove the plist -
   `rm /Library/LaunchDaemons/net.conceited.RubbernetDaemon.plist`
6. remove the app - delete `Rubbernet.app` from `/Applications`

Writing this up because of the large number of "Uninstall Rubbernet" spam content sites that are promoting easy uninstall tools.  It should not be this hard to remove Rubbernet.

Background: [launchctl stack](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29056/launchctl-difference-between-load-and-start-unload-and-stop)